# How can I sort existing bot commands in an embed, based on either a category that I manually add, or based on the folders they are in?

Tags: discord.js

Right now I have code that puts all of my bot's commands into an embed automatically. However, it all looks fairly messy, and I'd like a way to sort my code based on function (e.g., a category for utilities, a category for support etc.).

I'm not really sure how I can do this.

Currently I have this code:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (client) => {
  const baseFile = 'command-base.js'
  const commandBase = require(`./${baseFile}`)

  const commands = []

  const readCommands = (dir) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir))
    for (const file of files) {
      const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        readCommands(path.join(dir, file))
      } else if (file !== baseFile && file !== 'load-commands.js') {
        const option = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
        commands.push(option)
        if (client) {
          commandBase(client, option)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  readCommands('.')

  return commands
}
```

which goes into all of my project's folders and pulls out code, and this code that puts it all in an embed

```
 callback: (message, arguments, text) => {
    const commands = loadCommands()
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    embed.setTitle('Commands List')
    embed.setColor(`${embedColor}`)
    embed.setDescription('My prefix is `' + `${prefix}`+ '`. \n\n')
    let list = ' '
    for (const command of commands) {
   
    
      const mainCommand =
        typeof command.commands === 'string'
          ? command.commands
          : command.commands[0]
      const args = command.expectedArgs ? ` ${command.expectedArgs}` : ''
      const { description } = command
```

I'm not sure how I can sort my commands by folder.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

(sorry if this is written weird, it's my first time posting here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push your option into the array together with a bit of metadata - such as your path if you want to sort on that. Something like this:

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (client) => {
  const baseFile = 'command-base.js'
  const commandBase = require(`./${baseFile}`)

  const commands = []

  const readCommands = (dir) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir))
    for (const file of files) {
      const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        readCommands(path.join(dir, file))
      } else if (file !== baseFile && file !== 'load-commands.js') {
        const option = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
        // a value to sort on (in this case, the relative path):
        const optionPath = path.join(dir, file)
        commands.push({ option, optionPath })
        if (client) {
          commandBase(client, option)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  readCommands('.')
  // sort based on the earlier included optionPath:
  commands.sort((a, b) => { a.optionPath < b.optionPath ? -1 : 1 })

  return commands.map((cmd) => cmd.option) // (assuming that you don't need the extra fields)
}
```

Comment: what does the a.optionPath and b.optionPath stand for? Like the paths to certain folders, or..?

Comment: Added a few comments for clarity.